# jquery - Form input not saving

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a list of songs that gets pulled from a database on a page that has a form to add new songs. The adding and deleting functions both work fine. When I click on an existing song, it populates the form so it can be edited. The data is being sent to the fields correctly. However, when the form is submitted, it reloads the page, but nothing changes. Here is the current javascript:

```
$('.song-link').click(function(){
    // Fetching data
    var title = $(this).data('title');
    var band = $(this).data('band');
    var category = $(this).data('category');

    // Assigning data
    $('#title').val(title);
    $('#band').val(band);
    $('#category').val(category);
});
```

How can I get it to actually submit the data? I looked at it in the inspector and the value doesn't seem to change in the code, but it does visually.

Should I go about it another way?

**EDIT**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><?php _e("Song Title:", 'menu-test' ); ?> <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" size="20"></p>
    <p><?php _e("Band/Artist Name:", 'menu-test' ); ?> <input type="text" name="band" id="band" value="" size="20"></p>
    <p>
    <select name="category" id="category">
        <option value="Current and “All Time” Dance Hits">Current and “All Time” Dance Hits</option>
        <option value="R &amp; B, Motown, Disco">R &amp; B, Motown, Disco</option>
        <option value="80’s, 90’s, Rock">80’s, 90’s, Rock</option>
        <option value="Ballads">Ballads</option>
        <option value="Cocktail / Dinner Hour">Cocktail / Dinner Hour</option>
        <option value="Latin / Swing">Latin / Swing</option>
        <option value="Specialty">Specialty</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><?php _e("File:", 'menu-test' ); ?> <input type="file" name="file" /></p>
    <hr />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="1" />
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Save Changes') ?>" /></p>
</form>
```

It's within a worpdress site, so I'm using accessing the database via:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$song_check = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM song_list WHERE title = '".$title."'");
if(!$song_check){
    $wpdb->insert('song_list',array(
                                'title' => $_POST['title'],
                                'band' => $_POST['band'],
                                'category' => $_POST['category'],
                                'file' => $movefile['url']
                                ));
}else{
    $wpdb->update('song_list',array(
                                'title' => $_POST['title'],
                                'band' => $_POST['band'],
                                'category' => $_POST['category'],
                                ),
                            array(
                                'ID' => $_POST['id']
                                ));
}
```

Comment: You need to show your HTML.  Are you trying to use $.post?

Comment: What does for form look like? How is the info posted to the server? What does the server-side script looks like? What you posted gives very little information (read: "none information") on how the song actually is updated to the datebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prevent the default behavior for `anchor`:

```
$('.song-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()

    // Fetching data
    var title = $(this).data('title');
    var band = $(this).data('band');
    var category = $(this).data('category');

    // Assigning data
    $('#title').val(title);
    $('#band').val(band);
    $('#category').val(category);
});
```

Comment: I can't have it like that because I need the inputs to be populated with the existing data to be edited. Then submit the form. I've updated my question with more code to explain it better.

Comment: Then you just need the preventDefault. It's changing the URL when you click it!

Comment: I got it all working, including file updating by using the preventDefault and changing the database query just a little to take into account wether a new file has been added. Thank you! :)